# How to increase or decrease the distance between the two lines inside the Button?

Tags: excel, vba, button, userform

How to increase or decrease the distance between the two lines inside the Button?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You are able to customize some aspects of the button, but not the space between lines like you would do with a Word Document.

**UPDATE:** The only way to do this in the button of a form is with VBA. I tried some code like this:

`Me.cmd_button.Caption = "LALALA " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "LALALALALALALA"`

And i got this:

[image: **enter image description here**]

**UPDATE 2:** As @T.M. said, if you change the caption of the button, you must make sure to increase/reduce `me.cmd_button.Height` property to make the text readable. If you use several breaklines and you do not change the height of the button, text won'tbe appear.

Comment: ... and/or reducing the `cmd_button.Height` property as long as the `.Caption` property remains readable :-).

Comment: Indeed, of course. Height must be changed to make text readable. Thanks for observation.@T.M.

Comment: Which part of the code should I enter? Should I add in part Private Sub UserForm_Click()?

Comment: I do now know exactly what you need, but probably at the Load Event of the Form

Answer (score 0):

I use the **Ctrl+Enter** to make two lines of text. To make a distance, I repeat this again (Something like Enter in the Word program). But the distance created is high!.

[image]

Comment: The gap between both lines is determined by the `Font.Size` value you are using. Distance will be higher with `Font.Size=20` that with `Font.Size=8`.

Comment: Can you explain more? In which part? I do not think it's possible for each line! - @Foxfire And Burns And Burns

Comment: There is no more to explain. You can customize the text font and text size of the caption in a button. If you use big font size, gap will be higher. If you use small font size, gap will be smaller. That's all. And yes, you must use same values for all lines. It is not possible for each line.